# Can't get res.redirect to wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here's an example of the backend for a post method to update a blog that I'm working on:

```
app.post('/blogUpdate', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {

  try {

    const newContent = req.body.blogInput
    const template = '<p>' + newContent.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '</p><p>').replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p>'
    const newDate = Date.now().toString() 
    const postDate = req.body.date       

    db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {

      if (err) throw (err)

      const contentUpdate = "UPDATE post SET content = ? WHERE date = ?" 
      const dateUpdate = "UPDATE post SET updatedDate = ? WHERE date = ?"
      const blogContentUpdate = mysql.format(contentUpdate, [template, postDate])
      const blogDateUpdate = mysql.format(dateUpdate, [newDate, postDate])

      await connection.query (blogContentUpdate, (err, _result)=> {

        if (err) throw (err)

       })

      await connection.query (blogDateUpdate, (err, _result)=> {

        connection.release()
        if (err) throw (err)

       })

     })

    res.redirect('/blog')

  } catch {

  res.redirect('/blogInput')

  }

})
```

In this instance, I'm capturing modifications (req.body.blogInput) to an existing blog by selecting the original post date (a guaranteed unique UNIX value that is never modified, i.e. postDate), converting that to html (template), storing the new templated content into a database with a new updated date (newDate, which is put into a different SQL table field than the original postDate) then redirecting to a publicly available page that shows the blogs.  However, the redirect happens too quickly, and the edits don't show up on load.  That is, the old blog post content is shown.  A quick refresh always shows the edits that were just made.  How do I delay the redirect such that the edits will be visible upon loading of the redirect page?

Comment: Probably you are using the old callback-based mysql interface. `await` won't help you there as those calls don't return a promise. Either promisify it or look into promise-based alternatives like `mysql2`

Comment: Didn't get whole code but it seems redirect method executed while `db.getConnection` executing? You may add `db` method `await` and `.then` to execute redirect. Or put redirect method after `connection.query` method by `.then`.

Comment: There is already an `await`, and also no need to mix `then` with `await`. `connection.query` probably doesn't return a promise...

Comment: @CherryDT There is no `await` at `db.getConnection`.

Comment: The `await` keyword only works with promises, not callbacks.

Comment: @jacobkim Yes but the `redirect` is inside of its callback so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @CherryDT It's irrelevant to altering db from `mysql` to `mysql2`. It is possible to put `redirect`  in `then()` after `await db.getConnection` because it is still in `app.post()`. For a reference I written demo code below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this request.  I got it to work perfectly with a simple promise.

```
 app.post('/blogUpdate', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    
      try {
    
        const newContent = req.body.blogInput
        const template = '<p>' + newContent.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '</p><p>').replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p>'
        const newDate = Date.now().toString() 
        const postDate = req.body.date       
    
    
        **await new Promise** ((resolve, reject) => {

          db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {
    
          if (err) reject(err)
    
          const contentUpdate = "UPDATE post SET content = ? WHERE date = ?" 
          const dateUpdate = "UPDATE post SET updatedDate = ? WHERE date = ?"
          const blogContentUpdate = mysql.format(contentUpdate, [template, postDate])
          const blogDateUpdate = mysql.format(dateUpdate, [newDate, postDate])
    
          connection.query (blogContentUpdate, (err, result)=> {
    
            if (err) reject(err)

            return **resolve(result)**
           })
    
          connection.query (blogDateUpdate, (err, result)=> {
    
            connection.release()

            if (err) reject(err)
    
            return **resolve(result)**

           })
    
         })
  
        })

        res.redirect('/blog') 

      } catch {
    
      res.redirect('/blogInput')
    
      }
    
    })
```

By awaiting the resolved results, I could get the res.redirect function to wait.  Upon redirect, my post edits were immediately visible instead of having to reload the redirected page after the redirect.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that db method is awaited but redirect is executed already. So that redirect executing after awaiting db method.

```js
app.post('/blogUpdate', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {

  try {

    const newContent = req.body.blogInput
    const template = '<p>' + newContent.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '</p><p>').replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p>'
    const newDate = Date.now().toString() 
    const postDate = req.body.date       


// ----------- from this -----------------------//
    db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {

      if (err) throw (err)

      const contentUpdate = "UPDATE post SET content = ? WHERE date = ?" 
      const dateUpdate = "UPDATE post SET updatedDate = ? WHERE date = ?"
      const blogContentUpdate = mysql.format(contentUpdate, [template, postDate])
      const blogDateUpdate = mysql.format(dateUpdate, [newDate, postDate])

      await connection.query (blogContentUpdate, (err, _result)=> {

        if (err) throw (err)

       })

      await connection.query (blogDateUpdate, (err, _result)=> {

        connection.release()
        if (err) throw (err)

       })

     })
// ---------- till this executing --------------
    res.redirect('/blog') // but this executed while above method executing.

  } catch {

  res.redirect('/blogInput')

  }

})
```

```js
app.post('/blogUpdate', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {

  try {

    const newContent = req.body.blogInput
    const template = '<p>' + newContent.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '</p><p>').replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p>'
    const newDate = Date.now().toString() 
    const postDate = req.body.date       


// ----------- add await -----------------------//
   await db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {

      if (err) throw (err)

      const contentUpdate = "UPDATE post SET content = ? WHERE date = ?" 
      const dateUpdate = "UPDATE post SET updatedDate = ? WHERE date = ?"
      const blogContentUpdate = mysql.format(contentUpdate, [template, postDate])
      const blogDateUpdate = mysql.format(dateUpdate, [newDate, postDate])

      await connection.query (blogContentUpdate, (err, _result)=> {

        if (err) throw (err)

       })

      await connection.query (blogDateUpdate, (err, _result)=> {

        connection.release()
        if (err) throw (err)

       })

     })
// add await then after db, redirect method executing
  .then(() =>res.redirect('/blog'))
// ---------- --------------
    //res.redirect('/blog') // delete this

  } catch {

  res.redirect('/blogInput')

  }

})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  It's behaving the same.

Comment: I don't have your source to run so I can not find what the problem is exactly.